# How do I fix this error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"?

Tags: python, pandas, windows, error-handling, file-permissions

This is the snippet of the code which throws the error:

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')   
if os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx'):
        os.remove('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx')
```

I got this error message:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
another process: 'C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx'
```

I'm pretty sure the file in the path is not open. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the full traceback? Also, are you using jupyter?

Comment: yeah im using jupyter.

Comment: You probably ran another cell that opened the file. Restart the kernel and try again. Also, always close the writer when you are done: `writer.close()`

Comment: Restarted the kernel and also closed the writer after use--but still getting the error.

Comment: Is the file open in excel?

Comment: no its not open in excel

Comment: Is there a *really* good reason for the forward slash in the path? If not, try changing it to `'C:\\Users\\aji\\Curve.xlsx'`.

Comment: Why writing a file to delete it immediately afterwards? Also which line triggers the error? Most likely, a process from a previous run (that did not finish correctly), is keeping the file open. You must identify and kill it. If that doesn't work, re-login. Then as a last resort, reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're writing to the file properly. As a result, *your writer* has the file open.

According to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html?highlight=pandas%20excelwriter#pandas.ExcelWriter):

> The writer should be used as a context manager. Otherwise, call `close()` to save and close any opened file handles.

Try this instead (assuming the DataFrame you wish to write is stored in `df`):

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)

if os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx'):
    os.remove('C:\\Users\\aji/Curve.xlsx')
```

There are other good examples in the link I provided above. I suggest reviewing them in case another is a better fit for your use case.

And as a commenter suggested, mixing slashes is confusing. Either use backslashes everywhere, or forward slashes everywhere. But that shouldn't technically cause problems, it's just distracting.